# How to use / in a Datomic query?

Tags: java, clojure, datomic, datalog

This query

```
[:find ?p ?af
 :where [?p :person/age ?pa]
        [?p :person/father ?f]
        [?f :person/age ?fa]
        [(/ ?pa ?fa) ?af]]
```

returns only rounded (to 0 decimal places) values for `?af`, so I can't add sth. like

```
 [(< 0.25 ?af)]
 [(< ?af 0.5)]
```

to the :where clause.

I have tried casts to various types inside the query like

```
[(double ?pa) ?pa2]
```

but this only affects the result type and never removes the rounding.

If you know something and are experienced, I have quite a few more (especially type related) problems with Datomic. However I have not found a work-around for this division-query problem (except dividing after querying) and I really hope that it is not owed to the early development-stage of Datomic. I'd guess because Datomic does not support the Ratio type, they are rounding, but a few decimal places would be really nice.

I am using Datomic with Clojure.

**EDIT** I found a work-around for this, however I would still like to know why it is necessary.

Work-around:

- Use `clojure.core//`

  ```
  [:find ?p ?af
   :where [?p :person/age ?pa]
          [?p :person/father ?f]
          [?f :person/age ?fa]
          [(clojure.core// ?pa ?fa) ?af]]
  ```

But I certainly want to know which / is called (when invoked without a fully qualified namespace) and where I can find it's documentation so that I can learn about other possible problems with other operators.

**EDIT2:** Invoking an exception by designing a query to divide by zero, I found out that the static method `clojure.lang.Numbers/quotient` is invoked. 
How should I have known this?
It seems like Datomic is not opensource, at least I could not find the source-code in the jar file. 
Using `clojure.tools.trace` on `datomic.datalog`, I found out that the invoke happens by resolving `/` from `datomic.extensions`. In `datomic.extions`, `/` is defined as `clojure.core/quot`, which invokes `clojure.lang.Numbers/quotient`.

All this is undocumented as far as I am concerned.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem. It seems like a bug / undocumented "feature".

Comment: @ponzao: Thanks for reproducing! If that is a feature, their examples are really misleading. They use `*` like I use it on my HP calculator (http://docs.datomic.com/query.html). I have inquired about this in the Datomic usergroup yesterday and nobody has answered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it is an undocumented feature. Stuart Halloway has just confirmed this in the [Datomic group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/datomic/fYn0oDIZ3W4):

> Documentation for the operators available in query is missing, as you
>   discovered.  We are working on that, thanks for the report. The /
>   operator currently performs integer division only, and we are looking
>   into ways to make that richer without exposing consumers to a type
>   (ratio) that most JVM languages do not have.

Regarding the correct workaround I will keep this answer updated.